# How to solve no method error in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I defined my route and controller actions correctly. Still I'm getting a no method error.

Here is my code:

Route:

```
 get "/restaurants", to: "restaurants#index"
```

Controller action:

```
def index
  resto = Restaurant.all
  render json: resto,status: :ok
end
```

here is my error in the browser:

```
NoMethodError in RestaurantsController#index
undefined method `type' for #<Restaurant:0x00007fb711a07628>
Extracted source (around line #4):
              
    def index
     resto=Restaurant.all
    ( render json: resto,status: :ok) # this is the line throwing error

    end
end
```

And here is the problem in the console

```
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/restaurants" for ::1 at 2022-08-16 22:26:25 +0530
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by RestaurantsController#index as HTML
  Restaurant Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants"
  ↳ app/controllers/restaurants_controller.rb:4:in `index'
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (12.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 7.5ms | Allocations: 17269)
```

Comment: Any clue where that `type` method call is being invoked? Is there any serialization involved?

Comment: Is there a method `Restaurant#attributes` that mentions `type`? Do you expect `Restaurant#type` to return something, or do you have no idea what `Restaurant#type` would be expected to do? Does your application show a longer backtrace when the error appears in the browser?

Comment: `render json: resto.as_json`

Comment: Is your `Restaurant` model a subclass of another model?  Add to your question your Restaurant model and the full stack trace.

Comment: you are using rails serializer, can you please add serializer and model in your question?